# ASP.NET View redirect

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

In my layout I have a menu with links one of which is:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Whatistesting", "Testing")">What is testing</a></li>
```

On localhost this link works as expected and redirects to the appropriate controller and appropriate action. But i've published and all i get a 404 errors yet the path indicated is exactly what it ought to be. Any ideas?

Comment: The deployed server is setup for MVC? App pool setup with the correct ASP.Net runtime and all that?

Comment: No, you're not setup for MVC. The runtime would parse that string and convert it into a URL, which it obviously isn't doing. You need to get your site setup properly on your server.

Comment: Requested URL: /Testing/Whatistesting is what I'm getting. I'm using somee.com (free version) to test as I develop so I don't think it's a config issue.  either way, changing server settings is out of my control.

Comment: If you browse to the root of your site, what happens?

Comment: Correctly goes to my index view for home controller

Comment: what hapens when you request your website url with this action and controller ? Try using browser tools and check the url generated in the page

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks but i got it to work using this solution after Googling a bit
One reason this could occur is if you don't have a start page set under your web project's properties. So do this:

```
Right click on your mvc project
Choose "Properties"
Select the "Web" tab
Select "Specific Page"
Assuming you have a controller called HomeController and an action method called Index, enter "home/index" in to the text box corresponding to the "Specific Page" radio button.
```